# Snake game in C

Tags: performance, c, game, snake-game

Here is a very basic Snake game in C, which I just want to make better. The game is working perfectly but it is very annoying because when playing it, it is always blinking. I hope that somebody could try it in their compiler to see how annoying it is. How can I improve this?

Here is a screen shot of the game:

[image]

Of course it works, but I just need some advice about the design.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define UP 72
#define DOWN 80
#define LEFT 75
#define RIGHT 77

int length;
int bend_no;
int len;
char key;
void record();
void load();
int life;
void Delay(long double);
void Move();
void Food();
int Score();
void Print();
void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void GotoXY(int x,int y);
void Bend();
void Boarder();
void Down();
void Left();
void Up();
void Right();
void ExitGame();
int Scoreonly();

struct coordinate{
    int x;
    int y;
    int direction;
};

typedef struct coordinate coordinate;

coordinate head, bend[500],food,body[30];

int main()
{

    char key;

    Print();

    system("cls");

    load();

    length=5;

    head.x=25;

    head.y=20;

    head.direction=RIGHT;

    Boarder();

    Food(); //to generate food coordinates initially

    life=3; //number of extra lives

    bend[0]=head;

    Move();   //initialing initial bend coordinate

    return 0;

}

void Move()
{
    int a,i;

    do{

        Food();
        fflush(stdin);

        len=0;

        for(i=0;i<30;i++)

        {

            body[i].x=0;

            body[i].y=0;

            if(i==length)

            break;

        }

        Delay(length);

        Boarder();

        if(head.direction==RIGHT)

            Right();

        else if(head.direction==LEFT)

            Left();

        else if(head.direction==DOWN)

            Down();

        else if(head.direction==UP)

            Up();

        ExitGame();

    }while(!kbhit());

    a=getch();

    if(a==27)

    {

        system("cls");

        exit(0);

    }
    key=getch();

    if((key==RIGHT&&head.direction!=LEFT&&head.direction!=RIGHT)||(key==LEFT&&head.direction!=RIGHT&&head.direction!=LEFT)||(key==UP&&head.direction!=DOWN&&head.direction!=UP)||(key==DOWN&&head.direction!=UP&&head.direction!=DOWN))

    {

        bend_no++;

        bend[bend_no]=head;

        head.direction=key;

        if(key==UP)

            head.y--;

        if(key==DOWN)

            head.y++;

        if(key==RIGHT)

            head.x++;

        if(key==LEFT)

            head.x--;

        Move();

    }

    else if(key==27)

    {

        system("cls");

        exit(0);

    }

    else

    {

        printf("\a");

        Move();

    }
}

void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{

 COORD coord;

 coord.X = x;

 coord.Y = y;

 SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);

}
void GotoXY(int x, int y)
{
    HANDLE a;
    COORD b;
    fflush(stdout);
    b.X = x;
    b.Y = y;
    a = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(a,b);
 }
 void sleep(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();
    while (goal > clock());
}
void load(){
    int row,col,r,c,q;
    gotoxy(36,14);
    printf("loading...");
    gotoxy(30,15);
    for(r=1;r<=20;r++){
    sleep(200);//to display the character slowly
    printf("%c",177);}
    getch();
}
void Down()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=(head.y-bend[bend_no].y)&&len<length;i++)
    {
        GotoXY(head.x,head.y-i);
        {
            if(len==0)
                printf("v");
            else
                printf("*");
        }
        body[len].x=head.x;
        body[len].y=head.y-i;
        len++;
    }
    Bend();
    if(!kbhit())
        head.y++;
}
void Delay(long double k)
{
    Score();
    long double i;
    for(i=0;i<=(10000000);i++);
}
void ExitGame()
{
    int i,check=0;
    for(i=4;i<length;i++)   //starts with 4 because it needs minimum 4 element to touch its own body
    {
        if(body[0].x==body[i].x&&body[0].y==body[i].y)
        {
            check++;    //check's value increases as the coordinates of head is equal to any other body coordinate
        }
        if(i==length||check!=0)
            break;
    }
    if(head.x<=10||head.x>=70||head.y<=10||head.y>=30||check!=0)
    {
        life--;
        if(life>=0)
        {
            head.x=25;
            head.y=20;
            bend_no=0;
            head.direction=RIGHT;
            Move();
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            printf("All lives completed\nBetter Luck Next Time!!!\nPress any key to quit the game\n");
            record();
            exit(0);
        }
    }
}
void Food()
{
    if(head.x==food.x&&head.y==food.y)
    {
        length++;
        time_t a;
        a=time(0);
        srand(a);
        food.x=rand()%70;
        if(food.x<=10)
            food.x+=11;
        food.y=rand()%30;
        if(food.y<=10)

            food.y+=11;
    }
    else if(food.x==0)/*to create food for the first time coz global variable are initialized with 0*/
    {
        food.x=rand()%70;
        if(food.x<=10)
            food.x+=11;
        food.y=rand()%30;
        if(food.y<=10)
            food.y+=11;
    }
}
void Left()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=(bend[bend_no].x-head.x)&&len<length;i++)
    {
        GotoXY((head.x+i),head.y);
       {
                if(len==0)
                    printf("<");
                else
                    printf("*");
        }
        body[len].x=head.x+i;
        body[len].y=head.y;
        len++;
    }
    Bend();
    if(!kbhit())
        head.x--;

}
void Right()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=(head.x-bend[bend_no].x)&&len<length;i++)
    {
        //GotoXY((head.x-i),head.y);
        body[len].x=head.x-i;
        body[len].y=head.y;
        GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
        {
            if(len==0)
                printf(">");
            else
                printf("*");
        }
        /*body[len].x=head.x-i;
        body[len].y=head.y;*/
        len++;
    }
    Bend();
    if(!kbhit())
        head.x++;
}
void Bend()
{
    int i,j,diff;
    for(i=bend_no;i>=0&&len<length;i--)
    {
            if(bend[i].x==bend[i-1].x)
            {
                diff=bend[i].y-bend[i-1].y;
                if(diff<0)
                    for(j=1;j<=(-diff);j++)
                    {
                        body[len].x=bend[i].x;
                        body[len].y=bend[i].y+j;
                        GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                        printf("*");
                        len++;
                        if(len==length)
                            break;
                    }
                else if(diff>0)
                    for(j=1;j<=diff;j++)
                    {
                        /*GotoXY(bend[i].x,(bend[i].y-j));
                        printf("*");*/
                        body[len].x=bend[i].x;
                        body[len].y=bend[i].y-j;
                        GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                        printf("*");
                        len++;
                        if(len==length)
                            break;
                    }
            }
        else if(bend[i].y==bend[i-1].y)
        {
            diff=bend[i].x-bend[i-1].x;
            if(diff<0)
                for(j=1;j<=(-diff)&&len<length;j++)
                {
                    /*GotoXY((bend[i].x+j),bend[i].y);
                    printf("*");*/
                    body[len].x=bend[i].x+j;
                    body[len].y=bend[i].y;
                    GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                        printf("*");
                   len++;
                   if(len==length)
                           break;
               }
           else if(diff>0)
               for(j=1;j<=diff&&len<length;j++)
               {
                   /*GotoXY((bend[i].x-j),bend[i].y);
                   printf("*");*/
                   body[len].x=bend[i].x-j;
                   body[len].y=bend[i].y;
                   GotoXY(body[len].x,body[len].y);
                       printf("*");
                   len++;
                   if(len==length)
                       break;
               }
       }
   }
}
void Boarder()
{
   system("cls");
   int i;
   GotoXY(food.x,food.y);   /*displaying food*/
       printf("F");
   for(i=10;i<71;i++)
   {
       GotoXY(i,10);
           printf("!");
       GotoXY(i,30);
           printf("!");
   }
   for(i=10;i<31;i++)
   {
       GotoXY(10,i);
           printf("!");
       GotoXY(70,i);
       printf("!");
   }
}
void Print()
{
   //GotoXY(10,12);
   printf("\tWelcome to the mini Snake game.(press any key to continue)\n");
  getch();
   system("cls");
   printf("\tGame instructions:\n");
   printf("\n-> Use arrow keys to move the snake.\n\n-> You will be provided foods at the several coordinates of the screen which you have to eat. Everytime you eat a food the length of the snake will be increased by 1 element and thus the score.\n\n-> Here you are provided with three lives. Your life will decrease as you hit the wall or snake's body.\n\n-> YOu can pause the game in its middle by pressing any key. To continue the paused game press any other key once again\n\n-> If you want to exit press esc. \n");
   printf("\n\nPress any key to play game...");
   if(getch()==27)
   exit(0);
}
void record(){
   char plname[20],nplname[20],cha,c;
   int i,j,px;
   FILE *info;
   info=fopen("record.txt","a+");
   getch();
   system("cls");
   printf("Enter your name\n");
   scanf("%[^\n]",plname);
   //************************
   for(j=0;plname[j]!='\0';j++){ //to convert the first letter after space to capital
   nplname[0]=toupper(plname[0]);
   if(plname[j-1]==' '){
   nplname[j]=toupper(plname[j]);
   nplname[j-1]=plname[j-1];}
   else nplname[j]=plname[j];
   }
   nplname[j]='\0';
   //*****************************
   //sdfprintf(info,"\t\t\tPlayers List\n");
   fprintf(info,"Player Name :%s\n",nplname);
    //for date and time

   time_t mytime;
  mytime = time(NULL);
  fprintf(info,"Played Date:%s",ctime(&mytime));
     //**************************
     fprintf(info,"Score:%d\n",px=Scoreonly());//call score to display score
     //fprintf(info,"\nLevel:%d\n",10);//call level to display level
   for(i=0;i<=50;i++)
   fprintf(info,"%c",'_');
   fprintf(info,"\n");
   fclose(info);
   printf("wanna see past records press 'y'\n");
   cha=getch();
   system("cls");
   if(cha=='y'){
   info=fopen("record.txt","r");
   do{
       putchar(c=getc(info));
       }while(c!=EOF);}
     fclose(info);
}
int Score()
{
   int score;
   GotoXY(20,8);
   score=length-5;
   printf("SCORE : %d",(length-5));
   score=length-5;
   GotoXY(50,8);
   printf("Life : %d",life);
   return score;
}
int Scoreonly()
{
int score=Score();
system("cls");
return score;
}
void Up()
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<=(bend[bend_no].y-head.y)&&len<length;i++)
   {
       GotoXY(head.x,head.y+i);
       {
           if(len==0)
               printf("^");
           else
               printf("*");
       }
       body[len].x=head.x;
       body[len].y=head.y+i;
       len++;
   }
   Bend();
   if(!kbhit())
       head.y--;
}
```

Comment: Just use `gotoxy` instead of clearing the whole screen buffer with `system("cls")` that is why it is flushing all over again when updating. I have done this before :D

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Things that could be improved:

#### Portability:

- Every time you add an `#import` to the top of your C file, you potentially create a dependency.  For example: `#include <windows.h>` creates a dependency that the program can only be compiled on a Windows system.

  > ```
  > #include <stdio.h>
  > #include <time.h>
  > #include <stdlib.h>
  > #include <conio.h>
  > #include <time.h>
  > #include <ctype.h>
  > #include <time.h>
  > #include <windows.h>
  > #include <process.h>
  > #include <unistd.h>
  > ```

  You should always try to create a program so that it is as portable as possible, and can be played on a variety of systems.  Right now, your game can only be played on a few select systems.

#### Conventions/Standards:

- You don't follow proper C naming conventions for method names.

  > ```
  > void Delay(long double);
  > void Move();
  > void Food();
  > int Score();
  > void Print();
  > void gotoxy(int x, int y);
  > void GotoXY(int x,int y);
  > void Bend();
  > void Boarder();
  > void Down();
  > void Left();
  > void Up();
  > void Right();
  > void ExitGame();
  > int Scoreonly();
  > ```

  Either use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), or [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) with method names.
- You should have *unique* method names.

  > ```
  > void gotoxy(int x, int y);
  > void GotoXY(int x,int y);
  > ```

  Be more expressive with your function naming.
- You don't `typedef` a `struct` in the standard way, nor do you use proper naming conventions of `typedef struct`s.

  > ```
  > struct coordinate{
  >     int x;
  >     int y;
  >     int direction;
  > };
  >
  > typedef struct coordinate coordinate;
  > ```

  You can combine these two together for the proper definition of a `typedef struct`.  Also, you should always capitalize the first letter of the `typedef struct` name.

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
      int x;
      int y;
      int direction;
  } Coordinate;
  ```
- Don't use a `for` loop in the place of `sleep()`.

  > ```
  > for(i=0;i<=(10000000);i++);
  > ```

  There are many problems with [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) instead of using [`sleep()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  See [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/42506/27623) for more information.
- If you don't take in any variables as parameters, you should declare them as `void`.

  ```
  int main(void)
  ```
- Define `i` inside of your `for` loop.<sup>(C99)</sup>

  ```
  for(int i = 4; i < length; i++)
  ```

#### Styling:

- You have *way* too much space in some areas of your program.

  > ```
  > int main()
  > {
  >
  >     char key;
  >
  >     Print();
  >
  >     system("cls");
  >
  >     load();
  >
  >     length=5;
  >
  >     head.x=25;
  >
  >     head.y=20;
  >
  >     head.direction=RIGHT;
  >
  >     Boarder();
  >
  >     Food(); //to generate food coordinates initially
  >
  >     life=3; //number of extra lives
  >
  >     bend[0]=head;
  >
  >     Move();   //initialing initial bend coordinate
  >
  >     return 0;
  >
  > }
  > ```

  I'm all for using whitespace, but there are limits to everything.  Cut back on it a bit, right now the amount of whitespace you are using makes this program unreadable.

#### Syntax:

- You have some `#define`s that are related to each other.

  > ```
  > #define UP 72
  > #define DOWN 80
  > #define LEFT 75
  > #define RIGHT 77
  > ```

  These are all related to each other because they are all directions.  Therefore, we can group them together in an `enum`.

  ```
  typedef enum
  {
      UP = 72;
      DOWN = 80;
      LEFT = 75;
      RIGHT = 77;
  } Direction;
  ```
- Use [`puts()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/) instead of `printf()` when you are not formatting strings.

Answer (score 10):

The "annoying blinking" is probably caused by your calling `system("cls");` at the top of your `Boarder()`  function, which you call repeatedly from inside your `Move()` function. It would blink less if you didn't clear the screen every time your redraw the border, and/or if you didn't redraw the border for every move.