# Delaying a function call for 30 seconds using sleep() or checking the time in a loop

Tags: c++, c, reinventing-the-wheel, linux, timer

I need a way to delay a function call by 30 seconds on a machine that runs on electric power, not battery (if it matters). I have heard from my colleague not to use `sleep`, but [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/using-a-for-loop-instead-of-sleeping/42508#42508) suggests it:

> ```
> sleep(30) // sleep for 30 sec
> ```

Reasons invoked for not using `sleep` include:

1. I will violate Single Responsibility Principle.
2. Abstraction leak, etc.

Not sure why though; I feel it's good because it reduces CPU load and executes important tasks. In the below approach I am trying to just avoid `sleep` because I am asked not to use it though I am curious to know what a better (best?) approach would be?

```
void waiting (unsigned int secs)
{
        unsigned int retTime = time(0) + secs;   // Get finishing time.
        while (time(0) < retTime);               // Loop until it arrives.
}
```

Comment: What platform are you targeting, and how exact does the timing need to be?

Comment: What is your colleague's reasoning for avoiding `sleep`?

Comment: Waiting in a spinlock is a bad idea unless the time is very small. If the machine runs on a battery or with poor cooling conditions, chances are that the non sleeping approach will actually cause CPU to throttle performance due to overheat or kill battery very fast.

Comment: This question is [being discussed in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35562273#35562273).

Comment: How is `sleep` a SRP violation or an abstraction leak?

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason to avoid doing `sleep(30);`. Your colleague's concerns about the single responsibility principle and abstraction leak are unfounded. `sleep()` is designed to do exactly what you want, so why not use it? Constantly checking the time in a tight loop is a giant waste of computing power for no advantage at all.

Answer (score 4):

A mixture of both is more appropriate. [`sleep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/sleep.3posix.html) may exit even before the amount of seconds is over, so if you want to make sure that you don't exit to soon, you have to check the current time:

```
void waiting (unsigned int secs)
{
    time_t current = time(NULL);
    const time_t stop = current + secs;

    while(current < stop) {
        sleep(stop - current);
        current = time(NULL);
    }        
}
```

Note that this solution only needs C features. However, it uses the non-standard function `sleep`, which *might* not be available on the target system. Luckily, C++11 and C11 provide their own ways to sleep, e.g.

```
void waiting (unsigned int secs)
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(secs));
}
```

This one is guaranteed to sleep at least `secs` seconds, although it may sleep longer.

Either way, a busy-loop is just wasting resources.